# How to append a vector to a list of data.frames?

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply

How can I cbind/append a vector to a list of data.frames?

```
l <- list(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3)), data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(1,2,3,4)))
l
file_name <- c("myfile.txt", "yourfile.txt")
file_name
```

I tried:

```
lapply(l, function(x) cbind(l[[x]], fname = rep(file_name, each = nrow(l[[x]]))))
```

but I get an error:

> Error in l[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to `create a new column 'fname' for each of the`list` elements by appending the corresponding 'file_name' to it

```
Map(cbind, l, fname = file_name)
```

---

If we are using `lapply`, then loop through the sequence of the `list`

```
lapply(seq_along(l), function(i) transform(l[[i]], fname = file_name[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure.. you have the following list of data.frames..

```
l <- list(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3)), data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(1,2,3,4)))
l
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[2]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

Where you eventually want to cbind a vector (which differ per list) to all data.frames in the list.. so you want to have

```
[[1]]
  a b v
1 1 1 a
2 2 2 b
3 3 3 c

[[2]]
  a b v
1 1 1 a
2 2 2 b 
3 3 3 c
4 4 4 d
```

One trick that we can do is to first use rbindlist to get all of the frames together.. and keep their id's

```
L = rbindlist(l,idcol = TRUE)
```

And let's say that we also have a list that we wanted to append to each data.frame

```
v = list(data.frame(v = letters[1:3]), data.frame(v = LETTERS[1:4]))
V = rbindlist(v)
```

Now we can do a simple cbind and then split the list using the .id that we created

```
result = cbind(L,V)
final_result = split(result,on = ".id")

    $`1`
   .id a b v
1:   1 1 1 a
2:   1 2 2 b
3:   1 3 3 c

$`2`
   .id a b v
1:   2 1 1 A
2:   2 2 2 B
3:   2 3 3 C
4:   2 4 4 D
```

We still have an .id column there.. but that shouldnt be too much trouble to get rid of that one..